# What replaced [Obsolete] MvcRoute in MvcContrib?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-3

We're currently using `MvcContrib.Routing.MvcRoute` for our routes, but it's marked as `Obsolete` in version 3.0.51.0. Was the fluent API replaced by something or just abandoned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [changelog](http://markmail.org/message/sdvkcivcomh6fixr):

```
Deprecated MvcRoute and RegexRoute. Not maintained in nearly 2 years
```

Simply use the standard Route class in Mvc. Or if there is some functionality that you depend upon you could continue using it but bare in mind that the support for it has been dropped.

And here's the [response from Jeremy](http://markmail.org/message/o5qkwihek2j2vrsz):

> The only real issue with MvcRoute is that it doesn't work with areas,
>   which limits its usefulness. I'm not intending to remove it anytime
>   soon, but I think MVC's built in MapRoute extension methods are
>   probably a better choice going forward.

Comment: The big thing missing from the `MapRoute()` extensions is strong typing for the default action.

Comment: @dahlbyk, yes, that's true. Everyone loves strong typing. Well, you asked for facts about the Obsolete attribute and I provided you facts. But if you are like me and don't use Areas in your applications you could continue using this extension method. Maybe in ASP.NET 4 we will see some better ways to declare routes.